# Repeating bitmap not rendering well on view's state_pressed

Tags: android, xml, bitmap

I'm using a selector to animate my views, and in one of it i'm doing like this:

- View:

  ```
  <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="horizontal"
      android:weightSum="1"
      android:background="@drawable/selector_gridview" >
  ```
- selector_gridview:

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

      <item
          android:state_pressed="false"
          android:drawable="@drawable/selector_gridview_normal" 
      />

      <item 
          android:state_pressed="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/selector_gridview_pressed" 
      />

  </selector>
  ```
- selector_gridview_pressed:

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

      <item>
          <shape>
              <solid android:color="@color/overlayed" />

              <stroke 
                  android:width="1px"
                  android:color="#cccac3" />
          </shape>
      </item>

       <item>
          <bitmap
              android:antialias="true"
              android:dither="true"
              android:src="@drawable/bg_stripes_dark"
              android:tileMode="repeat" />
      </item>

  </layer-list>
  ```
- bg_stripes_dark is a .png located in `drawable-nodpi` folder.

The bitmap is the same for `selector_gridview_normal` and `selector_gridview_pressed`, but when the view is pressed the bitmap does not repeat like it does when the view isn't pressed.

I'm using a `MDPI / API 8 device`, in 4.0 devices (and so) this problem doesn't exist.

This seems to be a problem with the Support v4 Gridview. Actually it seems to have many problems. Is there any way to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an unfortunate bug that we fix in Android 3.0+ (I don't remember in what version exactly.) One way to work around this bug is to get a reference to the `BitmapDrawable` after you've loaded it and to manually set the tile mode to repeat from code using [setTileModeXY()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/BitmapDrawable.html#setTileModeXY%28android.graphics.Shader.TileMode,%20android.graphics.Shader.TileMode%29).

Comment: Thanks but I need some example code to get the reference of the background as a `BitmapDrawable`. It is a `LayerDrawable` as you can see.

Comment: The easiest way is to do ((BitmapDrawable) ((LayerDrawable) getBackgroundDrawable()).findDrawableByLayerId(R.id.myLayer)).setTileModeXY(...);

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps You-

//**backrepeatnormal.xml**

```
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/selector_gridview_normal" 
    android:tileMode="repeat" />
```

//**backrepeatpressed.xml**

```
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/selector_gridview_pressed" 
    android:tileMode="repeat" />
```

//**selector_gridview.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/backrepeatnormal" 
    />

    <item 
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/backrepeatpressed" 
    />

</selector>
```

//**layout file**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:background="@drawable/selector_gridview" >
```

Comment: What's the difference? You are saying to create a bitmap with the layer-list that I already had. It doesn't add any more properties and I think I get an error for trying to send a layer-list to a bitmap's src

Comment: you have not repeated the pressed image that why its not repeated.

Comment: The normal image is not repeated as well, i set the `tileMode` on both drawables